# Completing a web form using R

Tags: r, forms, authentication, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data from a website using R, but every once in a while it asks for my password. How can I have R fill in the form?

The html code for the form looks like this:

```
<form action="/en/login" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="http://website.com/" />

            <div style="margin-top:10px;">
      <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="" class="inputLoginBox" placeholder="your username" tabindex="1"/></td>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
      <input type="password" id="password" name="_password"  class="inputLoginBox" placeholder="your password"  tabindex="2"/></td>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
      <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" class="inputCheckbox" tabindex="3"/>
      <label for="remember_me">remember me</label>
      &nbsp;<a href='http://website.com/forum/ucp.php?mode=sendpassword' border="0" rel="nofollow" class="alt">forgot password?</a>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
      <button type="submit" class="submitButton"  name="login[go]" tabindex="4" style="font-size:1.3em;">login</button>
      <br><br>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: The package rvest and the function form are an option. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50391282/rvest-xml-web-scraping

Comment: rselenium is nice too

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez Thanks, that was helpful. Do you know how I can write all the html code from the webpage after I follow the instructions from that link? I tried write(read_html(set), "file.txt")

Comment: Certainly. If you captured the webpage through xml2´s read_html(), then you can employ write_html() to write it to your hd.

Comment: Can you provide the url of the web form you are trying to fill?